# convert pdf color to black and white

Tags: pdf, postscript

I am looking for an (open-sourced, or at least free) solution to tune the color of a pdf (or equivalently, ps) file, to black-and-white. Here are some technical specifications.

1. It should NOT be gray scale. It must contain at most two colors: black and white.
2. It handles a long pdf file in reasonable time (say, a file with 30 pages, in one or two minutes). This requires the process to be automated.
3. No significant resolution loss. Converting a pdf file to png/jpeg, thresholding the color and converting it back is a possible way, but as long as one requires 400+dpi resolution for a 30-page document, this way is too slow.

I appreciate it even if one lists some hints. I have tried `pdftk a.pdf output b.pdf uncompress` to uncompress the file, changing all the color definitions to be `0 0 0 1 k` or `0 g` or `0 0 1 rg`, but when I print the files out, it is still gray, not black.

Comment: Are the documents mainly text, or are there line art and images to be expected?

Comment: Mainly text, plus a small amount of possible vector pictures (typically, journal paper). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you can use

```
convert -density 150 -threshold 50% input.pdf output.pdf
```

But careful with the final quality, it will convert all text to images

I hope it works for you

Comment: convert-im6.q16: no images defined `foo.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.